# How to expose a port+url visible to one machine to another

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking, vlan, ssh-tunnel

Essentially I have 3 machines:

A, B and C

A can see B (and vice versa) and B can see C (and vice versa). A can't see C (not part of the same network).

I have access to A and B. Meaning I can start an ssh tunnle between A and B, but not between B and C.

I want to find the easiest way possible to access C:4444 from A.

I assume it would be possible via opening an ssh tunnel from A to B but I haven't found a way to do this via ssh tunneling. thought I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ServerB can directly reach ServerC:4444:

On ServerA:

```
ssh user@serverB -L 4444:ServerC:4444
```

Now you can connect to port 4444 on ServerA, which will be tunneled through ServerB to ServerC.

Comment: No, that is not possible, I'll try to make it more explicit in the post. Hence why I mentioned I only have access (via ssh) to server B and A.

Comment: According to your question, this should work (ServerA is only connecting to ServerB and then uses the tunnel provided by ServerB to ServerC). Have you actually tried it? Can you access port 4444 on ServerC from ServerB? Is it TCP?

Comment: Sorry, miss-read the answer the first time over... I did try the whole port:domain:port thing but with `-R` and to be it made sense it would work with `-R` not `-L`... hmh, silly me, thank you